# Warning: "Safe call on a non-null receiver will have nullable type in future releases" due to nullable variable in buildvariants

Tags: kotlin, nullable, build-variant

I'm developing an android app using Kotlin.
I have two different build-variants - `VariantA` and `VariantB` - both containing a configuration-File:

```
// VariantA
object ConfigEnvironment {
    val SOME_PARAMETER: String? = null
}

// VariantB
object ConfigEnvironment {
    val SOME_PARAMETER: String = "This is a config"
}
```

In my code i'm calling:

```
ConfigEnvironment.SOME_PARAMETER?.let { Log.d("tag", "$it" }
```

When building VariantB the Compiler throws a warning:

```
Safe call on a non-null receiver will have nullable type in future releases
```

While this is correct for this variant, it's somewhat impractical - since i need the nullability in the other variant.

Can i safely supress this lint?
(And how do i do that? My IDE didn't suggest any fixes)

Comment: If there are variants of you app, that must support `null`s for this property, wouldn't it be easier to just assume SOME_PARAMETER is nullable, that is, declaring `val SOME_PARAMETER: String? = "This is a config"` in your `VariantB`?

Comment: This would be the fastest solution, however, i don't like to give up some null-safety just because of a lint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be safe to suppress this warning since you do not call something which expects a non-nullable expression for `it` inside the `let`.

You can suppress the warnung like this:

```
@Suppress("UNNECESSARY_SAFE_CALL")
ConfigEnvironment.SOME_PARAMETER?.let { Log.d("tag", "$it") }
```

IntelliJ can help you with that. Just move the cursor to the `?.` and type your shortcut for Quick Fix (you can look it up in the Keyboard settings):
[image: screenshot of IntelliJ]

Comment: Oooooh i hadn't seen the submenu. Thanks!

Comment: You can also suppress a similar warning for fields with explicit types, like `val parameter: String? = BuildConfig.DEBUG_PARAMETER` using this suppression: `@Suppress("RedundantNullableReturnType")`